# Hiding / disabling UIButton and UIBarButtonItem

Tags: xcode, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

Really stumped here. I keep reading posts, nothing works and I get more confused.

I have an info button named "info", and a bar button item named "backnav". Given the differences in the fact that info is a UIButton and backnav is a UIBarButtonItem, I used both `info.hidden = YES` and `backnav.enabled = NO`. Neither work. I've also used the `[info setHidden:YES];` and `[backnav setEnabled:NO]`, and neither of those options work. Do these buttons have to be declared as `-(void)` in order to be hidden/disabled, or is `-(IBAction)` okay?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try logging to make sure that `info` and `backnav` are even meaningful references:

```
 NSLog(@"%@\n%@", info, backnav);
```

I'm betting they are nil. You need working outlets here, and I'm thinking you don't have them.

Comment: What an outlet is, and the many ways to make one: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_outlet_connections

Comment: OK, my apologies. I am ridiculous... I found out that I am now able to connect them to the File's Owner, but I wasn't able to do that before, so I must have just barely gotten the syntax right for the option to become available to me. Now my ONLY question: is there a way to flat out HIDE a UIBarButtonItem? Or am I limited to only `enabled = NO;`?

Comment: To hide the UIBarButtonItem, literally remove it from its bar (toolbar or nav bar).

Comment: That's what I thought. Bummer. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It's not really a bummer. Being nimble with manipulating the contents of a bar (toolbar or navbar) is quite standard, and a good habit. You can do a lot of cool stuff. You even get nice animation as you do this!

Comment: any chance you can offer input on how to hide the toolbar which contains the `UIBarButtonItem`? obviously i need to declare the toolbar in somewhere but i'm unsure how...

Comment: You want to hide the toolbar or the UIBarButtonItem? If the toolbar, it's just a view, you can set its `hidden`. Unless you are in a UINavigationController interface, in which case the UINavigationController itself helps you.

Comment: Well I want to hide the UIBarButtonItem only, but I'm under the impression you can't individually hide the button?...you need to hide the whole toolbar to do that?

Comment: I said, you remove the button from the toolbar. Just set the toolbar's items so that the button is not one of its items any more.

Comment: if you mean physically drag it out of the toolbar, i'd rather not because i want to keep the barbutton style to match the rest of my app. I don't know any other way to detach the button from the toolbar. I'm a newbie... :)

Comment: Have you considered reading the UIToolbar docs? Just call `setItems:animated:` with all the items *except* this one. This one will vanish. Yes, you will need either to keep a reference to it or have code for recreating it again later.

Comment: cool, i'll check it out. i did see something about it. i guess my frustration lies in that i think xcode (rather, objective C) could be much simpler. from an experienced programmer it may seem true, but for someone like me i suppose my expectations are that it would be an easy tool.... it can be tricky to grasp sometimes. thanks for all your help!

Comment: I think this part is quite straightforward. I've written a book that can help you: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_uitoolbar

Comment: Awesome! I'll check it out